# How to authenticate OAuth 1.0 keys and token in Karate DSL Feature file?

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, oauth, cucumber, karate

Having API Key, API Secret Key, Access Token and Access token Secret  for OAuth 1.0 authentication. Can any one share feature file to input keys and token in Karate DSL?

Comment: Read the docs and [demos](https://github.com/intuit/karate/tree/master/karate-demo), it will actually save you a lot of time: [`oauth1.feature`](https://github.com/intuit/karate/blob/master/karate-demo/src/test/java/demo/oauth/oauth1.feature)